# TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime')

Tags: flutter, datetime, casting, timestamp, typeerror

This is my flutter code:

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
print(response.body);
```

and the following is the result:

```
[{id: 9046fcba-8ed2-46a6-97f2-778749eea53b, created_at: 2023-02-24T21:44:38.654Z}]
```

And this is my model for this data:

```
class x with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final DateTime createdAt;
}
```

Also in the backend side I use such a model for that:

```
  interface IContest{
  id: Buffer;
  created_at: string;
}
```

Also the schema of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contests_local.locals(
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
);
```

But I get this error message: _

```
TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime')
```

When I try:

```
  extractedData.forEach((res) {
    loadedContests.add(Res(
      id: res['id'],
      createdAt: res['created_at'],
    ));
```

I know if I change my flutter model to the following the problem resolves, but I am not sure if is it a good practice or there is a better way to resolve it?

```
class x with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String createdAt;
}
```

Comment: Your date is definitely a string, but you can parse it into a date with `DateTime.parse(res['created_at'])

Comment: @RichardHeap: Would it be helpful if I do this conversion or keep it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `DateTime.tryParse()` method to convert your String into a DateTime. Here is the example code below

```
loadedContests.add(Res(
  id: res['id'],
  createdAt: DateTime.tryParse(res['created_at']),
));
```

Comment: As this is the first time I am working with time variables from database, do you know would it be helpful if I do this conversion or keep it as a string?